# how to set different text for spannable string?

Tags: android, spannablestring

[image]

In the following image, i am using spannable string to get the display like that. When i click on the time(12:00 PM), the time picker dialog will pop up and set the time. But when i set the time for first one, the second time also changes. how to avoid this? 
below is the following code i have written:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cancel_appointment_dialog, container, false);

    mCancellationReasonTextInput = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_cancellation_field);
    mCancelAllRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_appointment_radio_button);
    mCancelFromRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_appointment_from_radio_button);
    mCancelBetweenRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_appointment_between_radio_button);
    mBlockSlotsCheckBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.block_cancelled_slots_check_box);
    mNotifyPatientsCheckBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notify_patients_check_box);
    mOkButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);


    showSpannableStringBetween();

    mCancelFromRadioButton.setText(mSpannableStringFrom);
    mCancelFromRadioButton.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


    mOkButton.setOnClickListener(onOKButtonClick);

    return rootView;
}



void showSpannableStringBetween() {
    String titleText = " 12:00 PM";
    String sampleText = " and" + titleText;
    String resultText = getString(R.string.cancel_between_text) + titleText;  //61

    mSpannableFirstString = new SpannableString(resultText);

    mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), (resultText.length() - titleText.length()), resultText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(mClickableSpanBetween, (resultText.length() - titleText.length()), resultText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), (resultText.length() - titleText.length()), resultText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    mSpannableSecondString = new SpannableString(sampleText);
    mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), (sampleText.length() - titleText.length()), sampleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(mClickableSpanBetween, (sampleText.length() - titleText.length()), sampleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), (sampleText.length() - titleText.length()), sampleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    mCancelBetweenRadioButton.setText(TextUtils.concat(mSpannableFirstString , mSpannableSecondString));
    mCancelBetweenRadioButton.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

 ClickableSpan mClickableSpanBetween = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {

        int hour = getHour();
        int minute = getMinutes();

        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                String format;
                setHour(selectedHour);
                setMinutes(selectedMinute);

                if (selectedHour == 0) {

                    selectedHour += 12;

                    format = "AM";
                } else if (selectedHour == 12) {

                    format = "PM";

                } else if (selectedHour > 12) {

                    selectedHour -= 12;

                    format = "PM";

                } else {

                    format = "AM";
                }

                String timeText = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute + " " + format;

                String titleText = getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " " + timeText + " and " + timeText;

                mSpannableFirstString = new SpannableString(titleText);

                mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 46,53, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(mClickableSpanBetween, 46, 53, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mSpannableFirstString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 46, 53, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), (titleText.length() - timeText.length()), titleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(mClickableSpanBetween, (titleText.length() - timeText.length()), titleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mSpannableSecondString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), (titleText.length() - timeText.length()), titleText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                mCancelBetweenRadioButton.setText(mSpannableFirstString);

            }
        }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time

        mTimePicker.setTitle("Start Time");
        mTimePicker.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: please click on "display" to view the image

Comment: Try to use two different clickable span instead of one common

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: @Berkay92 thank you for the answer. It solved my problem to some extent.